# display data after http post in angular 7

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm new to angular, 
I'm using Angular 7 as client side and ASP.NET as server side
I'm trying to get data from HTTP post and display it into the html label element.

here's the html label(userError.Username is the field i want to display):

```
<label class="text-danger">{{userError.Username}}</label>
```

i'm initiating the field in the ngOnInit and the i see the field.

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.userError = new UsersError();
this.userError.Username = "123123";
}
```

when the page is loaded i see the 123123 in red(like it should)
when i receive data from http post(UsersError object) i'm changing the this.userError by assign data to it, but nothing happend.
here's the code:

```
Enter()
{
 this.userService.validate_user(this.user).subscribe(data => {this.userError 
 = data
console.log(this.userError);
}); 
}
```

from the console.log i see that the data received correctly( is see that Username gets a new value, however the  html element is empty.

Comment: Can you post the result of your console.log from the subscribe success callback ?

Comment: {UserID: null, UserName: "Username Invalid", FirstName: null, LastName: null, Email: null, …}
Active: null
BirthDate: null
Email: null
FirstName: null
LastName: null
Password: "Password Invalid"
Phone: null
Telephone: null
UserID: null
UserName: "Username Invalid"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Your object is returning a field named "UserName" and you are displaying "Username", which is a different variable since it's case-sensitive.

Comment: damn you right thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

according to @schankam answer i didn't notice that the field was not the same becuase it is case sensitive